# Resource to learn writing most efficient and highly optimized sql queries

Tags: oracle, performance, query-performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learning to Optimize SQL Queries and Understand Execution Plans - Resources?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20555/learning-to-optimize-sql-queries-and-understand-execution-plans-resources)

Can some one point me to a great book/great books or some really solid reference/references in the internet space that precisely deals in writing the most efficient and most optimized sql queries for Oracle?

Comment: There is no database-agnostic performance.  Tuning requires knowing how the optimizer and engines work, which means tuning specifically for the RDBMS and version.

Comment: @JNK then ofcourse as mentioned in my question itself I would like to learn the tricks for Oracle and SqlServer

Comment: I would say those are two separate questions.  You won't find a resource that addresses both.

Comment: @JNK I edited the question.

Comment: @LeighRiffel see the edited question now .